# Word Ladders go to the movies

Tags: knowledge, movies, word-ladder

<sup>An entry in [Fortnightly Topic Challenge #36: Twisted Classics 1](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6372)</sup>

---

You love movies.  You had several (9) VHS tapes, neatly organized in their sleeves, up on a shelf.  However, due to a certain *incident*, they've been mixed and their sleeves destroyed.  Luckily, the first and last tapes were unaffected and can still be identified.  You don't have time to watch them, so you'll have to find a different way to identify them.

You know they were put in order like a word-ladder with the following rules:

- Movie titles only (no TV, no shorts)
- Spaces and punctuation were excluded
- At least 4 consecutive letters had to appear in the next entry in (not necessarily consecutive) order.  So, a movie like Ra***in Ma***n could go into ***I***ro***n Ma***n
- The movies have some sort of connection between all of them

Of course, you also remember that your favorite movie of all time, *Spy Kids 2: Island of Lost Dreams*, is one of the movies.

```
The Prey
________________________
________________________
________________________
________________________
________________________
________________________
________________________
Cage
```

*Note: Beginning paragraph is mostly flavor-text with no real bearing on the puzzle, other than the fact that there are 9 movies, total.*

Comment: I feel like working from the bottom up might be easier than the other way

Comment: Considering that my favorite movie (in regards to this puzzle) is Spy Kids 2, I may want to consider checking into a hospital, to make sure I don't have brain damage before I sort out these movies.

Comment: Be sympathetic, @Joe-You-Know … David probably spent twice as much time trying to incorporate a less embarrassing alternative than _Spy Kids 2_ than he spent on the entire puzzle. :-)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The connection between all movies is, ...

> that [Danny Trejo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Danny_Trejo) was an actor in all of them.

Now we can fill the ladder (probably one of several possible solutions):

> [**The P**rey](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt2357423/) → **The** Re**p**lacement Killers
>  [The Replacement **Kill**ers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Replacement_Killers) → The **Kill**ing Jar
>  [The Kil**ling** Jar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Killing_Jar_(2010_film)) → **L**iv**ing** the Dream
>  [Living the **Dream**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Living_the_Dream_(film)) → Spy Kids 2: The Island of Lost **Dream**s
>  [Spy Kids 2: **The I**sland of Lost Dreams](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spy_Kids_2:_The_Island_of_Lost_Dreams) → Spy Kids: All **the** T**i**me in the World
>  [Spy Kids: All the Time i**n the** World](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spy_Kids:_All_the_Time_in_the_World) → Anchorma**n: The** Legend of Ron Burgundy
>  [An**chor**man: The Legend of Ron Burgundy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anchorman:_The_Legend_of_Ron_Burgundy) → **Ch**avez Cage of Gl**or**y
>  [Chavez **Cage** of Glory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chavez_Cage_of_Glory) → **Cage**
>  [Cage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cage_(film))

Alternative solution ...

> ... featuring all 4 Spy Kids movies:
>
>  [The **Prey**](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt2357423/) → **Pr**op**e**nsit**y**
>  [Pro**pens**ity](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0760180/) → S**p**y Kids 2: Th**e** Isla**n**d of Lo**s**t Dreams
>  [Spy Kids 2: **The I**sland of Lost Dreams](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spy_Kids_2:_The_Island_of_Lost_Dreams) → Spy Kids: All **the** T**i**me in the World
>  [**Spy K**ids: All the Time in the World](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spy_Kids:_All_the_Time_in_the_World) → **Spy K**ids
>  [Spy **Kids**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spy_Kids) → Spy **Kids** 3-D: Game Over
>  [Spy Kids 3-D: G**ame O**ver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spy_Kids_3-D:_Game_Over) → **A**nchor**m**an: Th**e** Legend **o**f Ron Burgundy
>  [An**chor**man: The Legend of Ron Burgundy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anchorman:_The_Legend_of_Ron_Burgundy) → **Ch**avez Cage of Gl**or**y
>  [Chavez **Cage** of Glory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chavez_Cage_of_Glory) → **Cage**
>  [Cage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cage_(film))

Answer (score 0):

Partial answer:

> **The Pre**y $\implies$ **The Pre**stige
>  **The Pres**tige $\implies$ All **the Pres**ident's Men
>  All the President'**s Men** $\implies$ Pirate**s** of the Caribbean: Dead **Men** Tell No Tales
>  Pirates **of the** Caribbean: Dead Men Tell No Tales $\implies$ Silence **of the** Lambs
>  Silence **of the** Lambs $\implies$ The Lord **of the** Rings: The Return of the King
>  The Lord of the Rings: The **Return of the** King $\implies$ Star Wars Episode VI - **Return of the** Jedi
>  Star Wars Episode VI - **Return of** the Jedi $\implies$ xXx: **Return of** Xander Cage
>  xXx: Return of Xander **Cage** $\implies$ **Cage**

Someone just needs to fill in the blanks about how there's a connection amongst them.

Comment: You forgot that *"Of course, you also remember that your favorite movie of all time, Spy Kids 2: Island of Lost Dreams, is one of the movies."*

Comment: Yeah, I mean I didn't put it in, but I also can't forget something that isn't true. My favourite movie of all time is Jurassic Park. ;)   I don't see a connection among The Prey, Spy Kids 2, and Cage, so I went with a random list instead.

Answer (score 0):

I've found all nines but can't find a connection between them:

(bold part is the consecutive letters that will appear on the next title, italic part is the letters from the previous title)

> **the p**rey
>  *the p*uni**sher**
>  *sher*lock holmes: A **game** of shadow
>  a ni*g*htm*a*re on el*m* stre*e*t 3: **dream** warriors
>  Spy Kids 2: Island **of Lo**st *Dream*s
>  Pirates *of* the Caribbean: **Dead** Men Te*l*l N*o* Tales
>  wrong **turn** 2: *dead* end
>  xxx: re*turn* of xander **cage**
>  *cage*

Comment: I have the impression, it makes more sense to find the connection between the movies first, instead of choosing movies based on 4 of 25 letters beeing equal.